# Paso de parametros entre clases Java

Tags: java, poo

La aplicación tiene que iniciarse y hay un menú en el que preguntas que tipo de loteria quieres, de momento PRIMITIVA, y al elegir esto hay que pedir al usuario la fecha que quiere adjuntar al boleto y 6 numeros(las apuestas a las que va a jugar para ver si toca). Me he quedado atascado en el momento en el que le pides la fecha, tengo la clase BOLETO(abstracta) y la clase PRIMITIVA(que hereda de la anterior), la idea es que todos los datos se guardan en la clase boleto para una vez están todos ahi, escribirlos en un archivo binario.

CLASE BOLETO(con sus getters y setters)

```
public abstract class Boleto implements Serializable{


private int codNum;
public String fechaSorteo;
private ArrayList apuesta;

public Boleto(String fecha)
{
    fechaSorteo = fecha;
}


public void guardar()
{
    Primitiva pr = new Primitiva("1/1/21");
        
         try{
        File ficheroBoleto = new File("C:\\Users\\sergi\\Desktop\\numerosBoletos.bol");
    
        FileOutputStream escritura = new FileOutputStream(ficheroBoleto, true);//True para añadir si existe el fichero
        
        int numeroBoleto = (int)(Math.random()*(10000-1+1))+1;
        
        escritura.write(numeroBoleto);
        
        for(int i=0;i<pr.numeros.length;i++)
        {
            escritura.write(pr.numeros[i]);
        }
        
        escritura.close();
        
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Fichero no encontrado");
    }catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }
         
}
```

CLASE PRIMITIVA

```
public class Primitiva extends Boleto{

private String tipoBoleto;
private int reintegro;
public  int numeros[] = new int[7];


public Primitiva(String fecha)
{
    super(fecha);
    tipoBoleto = "PRIMITIVA";
    
}

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);




public void elegirNumero() {
    int veces = 0;
    
     
    while(veces<6)
    {
        System.out.println("Introduce un numero");
        numeros[veces] = sc.nextInt();
        
        veces++;
    }
    
    
    numeros[7] = (int)(Math.random()*(49-1+1))+1;
    
}



@Override
public void generarNumero() {
    //int n = (int)(Math.random()*(b-a+1))+a
    for(int i=0;i<numeros.length;i++)
    {
        numeros[i] = (int)(Math.random()*(49-1+1))+1;
    }
    
}
```

Espero que se entienda mi duda, simplemente es con el tema de la fecha, en el main al elegir PRIMITIVA en el menú se ha de instanciar una primitiva y pedir la fecha y los numeros para guardarlos en un fichero. El problema es con el tema de la fecha. Ahora mismo el metodo guardar() solo escribe los numeros de la primitiva.

Comment: Me parece que tienes un lío, aplica un poco de Metafísica en tu modelo de datos, te será de gran ayuda... Si `Primitiva` es una lotería, y en esa lotería **entran `N` cantidad de `Boletos`** es absurdo hacer que `Primitiva` extienda de `Boleto`. Deberían ser **dos clases independientes** y `Primitiva` debe tener a un método para que le pases, no los boletos ni siquiera, sino un objeto `Sorteo`, que sería el que tendría una propiedad `fecha`  y una lista de objetos del tpo `Boleto`. Si no piensas la cosa desde el punto de vista metafísico, pronto estarás perdido en tu diseño de clases.

Comment: De quien `Primitiva` debería extender sería de una clase `Loteria`, porque **metafísicamente** `Primitiva` es un tipo de `Lotería`. No sé si me explico. Tú no puedes diseñar clases pensando en la conveniencia, porque al final esa aparente *conveniencia* se convierte en un gravísimo problema, como de hecho ocurre en tu código. Al leer esto: `public class Primitiva extends Boleto` estás diciendo que `Primitiva` es un tipo de `Boleto` ¿eso es cierto? Noooo. Un `Boleto`  es un objeto que se usa en `Primitiva`, dentro de un `Sorteo`. Ese es el orden **metafísico** de las cosas.

Comment: Lo mismo ocurre con el `Scanner` que has metido dentro de `Primitiva`. Ese objeto no tiene ningún sentido dentro de la clase `Primitiva`. Volvamos a la **metafísica**: el `Scanner` serían las sucursales (o peor aún, los compradores). Imaginate, hay miles de sucursales (o millones de compradores), ¿cómo las vas a meter todas dentro de `Primitiva`? Tener un `Scanner` dentro de la clase, significa que si hay un millón de sucursales donde se venden `Boletos` de `Lotería`, tienes que meter un millón de `Scanner` dentro de la clase. El `Scanner` para este caso debe ir en el `Main`.

Comment: Pero no se generan X numero de boletos, cuando aparece el menú tu eliges generar un Boleto de Primitiva o El Gordo o Euromillones(que serán otras clases que heredan de boleto, pero aun no he llegado). Boleto realmente solo lo uso para almacenar los datos que se generen en Primitiva y guardarlo en un fichero. No se si me he explicado mejor ahora

Comment: Que no, que ninguna de las loterías **debe heredar de `Boleto`**. Ese diseño está mal hecho así, por todo lo que te expliqué más arriba. Los objetos de tipo `Boleto` deben ser metidos en un `ArrayList`  y quien contendría esa lista de boletos sería `Sorteo`  y luego le pasas `Sorteo` a `Primitiva` para que saque el `Boleto` ganador. ¿No es así como funciona en la realidad? Y la `fecha` la tendría la instancia de `Sorteo`.

Comment: Vale creo que lo he terminado de entender. A ver si lo consigo aplicar

Comment: recuerda que en un `array` los indices inician de **0** en tu método `elegirNumero` si tu array tiene tamaño 7 ,no existe la posición `numeros[7]` , ese array declarado debe ser de tipo privado y obtener sus datos mediante el uso de `getter` asimismo el tamaño debe ser declarado dentro del metodo `elegirNumero` **this.numero=new int[7];** si vas a declararlo publico no tiene sentido que declares una instancia de la clase **Primitiva** en el metodo `guardar`.